# Hide Web App's URL Completely in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, url, web-applications

Is it possible to create a Chrome shortcut that will launch a web app in such a way that users will not be able to view or access the URL of the web app via Chrome, e.g., via the address bar, status bar, developer tools, etc. If not, would it be possible if I packaged the web app as a [Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)? I should note that I am not concerned about the shortcut itself containing the URL, e.g., in its "Properties", because I already have an executable will which launch the shortcut. All I care about is the user not being able to view the app from within Chrome itself once the app has been launched, at least not easily.

I have tried adding Chrome flags/switches, namely, kiosk mode, fullscreen mode, and app mode, but none of them work 100% as needed. Kiosk and fullscreen modes will launch as such only if no other instances of Chrome are open; if another instance of Chrome is already open, both modes will launch in a regular view mode in which users can see the URL in the address bar. App mode (I added "--app=http://www.example.com" to the end of the "Target" property of the shortcut) is promising because it launches with no browser chrome, but I notice that if I refresh the page while in app mode, I can see the URL both in the top window bar and the bottom-left status bar. Also, app mode doesn't prevent the user from opening Developer Tools, which makes viewing the URL trivial.

Any ideas welcome!

Comment: It goes directly against user's rights. Why would I visit a page without knowing which url it have? Security by obscurity is always a bad idea..

Comment: @Oscar, the web app is being deployed to a group of users who want the app to appear like a standard Windows application. They do not care to view the URL and actually requested that the URL be hidden, so it is not applicable in this case to say that hiding the URL would go against their rights. And to be clear, I am not asking about how the app itself could hide the URL but rather how a user (or someone working for the user) could intentionally launch a web app in the described way. In any case, I don't think this context is relevant: I simply want to know if it's possible and if so, how.